# Regular expression find/replace notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've a huge text file with lines like this:

```
080012;Bovalino;RC;CAL;0964;89034;B098;9021;http://www.website-most.en/000/000/
```

And i would like extract only:

```
080012;***Bovalino***;***RC***;CAL;***0964***;***89034***;B098;9021;http://www.website-most.en/000/000/
```

And delete all other text.

Can this be done with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the stuff you want to keep and use a backreference in the replacement string:

```
Find what: ^\d*;(\w*;\w*);\w*;(\d*;\d*).*
Replace with: \1;\2
```

And make sure you do **not** tick the `. matches newline` option.

With Notepad++ 6 you can also use `$1;$2` for the replacement (with the same meaning).

If the different fields may contain all sorts of characters and not just digits and letters, this is probably your best bet:

```
Find what: ^[^;]*;([^;]*;[^;]*);[^;]*;([^;]*;[^;]*).*
```

Comment: Will replace all lines with $1;$2  :(

Comment: @Luca Make sure you have updated to Notepad++ 6, they changed a lot of regex stuff there. Otherwise, try `\1;\2`

Comment: Some don't will be replaced :/

Comment: @Luca then I guess they have a different format. What do they look like?

Comment: For example this won't be replaced:  052001;Abbadia San Salvatore;SI;TOS;0577;53021;A006;6722;http://www.website-most.en/000/000/

Comment: @Luca yes, the problem are the spaces which I couldn't anticipate from the given example. See the last version in my answer, it will take care of all possible cases with the correct number of semicolons.